# how to resolve blank space between two div when fold

Tags: html, css, perspective

I want to resolve the question img:

[image: want to resolve the question img]

How to resolve the blank space when fold between the red and purple div ! 
is whether because of the **perspective** property ?
Thanks a lot!!!

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #333;
}

.fold-div {
  position: relative;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

#div1 {
  background: #d94f5c;
  animation-name: fold-top;
  transform-origin: top;
}

#div2 {
  background: #742fad;
  animation-name: fold-bottom;
  transform-origin: bottom;
}

@keyframes fold-top {
  100% {
    transform: perspective(50px) rotateX(-8deg);
    height: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes fold-bottom {
  100% {
    transform: perspective(50px) rotateX(8deg);
    height: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div class="fold-div" id="div1"></div>
<div class="fold-div" id="div2"></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Because of the rotateX, the perceived height of the block is less than the actual height. According to my calculations, for instance, halfway through the animation the perceived height would be the cosine of 4 degrees, .9975 or 99.75% of the calculated height (which is 50px at that point). That doesn't match the size of the gap we see though. Hm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inspire Jinu Kurian idea, i resolve the question by margin-bottom -10px when animation start!!! thanks Jinu Kurian a lot!!!

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #333;
}

.fold-div {
  position: relative;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

#div1 {
  background: #d94f5c;
  animation-name: fold-top;
  transform-origin: top;
}

#div2 {
  background: #742fad;
  animation-name: fold-bottom;
  transform-origin: bottom;
}

@keyframes fold-top {
  0% {
    margin-bottom: -10px;  // when animate, margin-bottom -10px
  }
  100% {
    transform: perspective(50px) rotateX(-8deg);
    height: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes fold-bottom {
  100% {
    transform: perspective(50px) rotateX(8deg);
    height: 0;
  }
}


thanks's Jinu Kurian, inspire by the idea, i resolve it when start animation 0% {
   margin-bottom: -10px
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
<div class="fold-div" id="div1"></div>
<div class="fold-div" id="div2"></div>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I just added a negative margin to fix this issue. see the snippet.

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #333;
}

.fold-div {
  position: relative;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

#div1 {
  background: #d94f5c;
  animation-name: fold-top;
  transform-origin: top;
  margin-bottom: -10px; // negative margin
}

#div2 {
  background: #742fad;
  animation-name: fold-bottom;
  transform-origin: bottom;
}

@keyframes fold-top {
  100% {
    transform: perspective(50px) rotateX(-8deg);
    height: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0; // reset margin to 0 to avoid a glitch bug 
  }
}

@keyframes fold-bottom {
  100% {
    transform: perspective(50px) rotateX(8deg);
    height: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div class="fold-div" id="div1"></div>
<div class="fold-div" id="div2"></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: ok. no problem. 
Please consider upvoting  accept this answer if your issue is fixed.